# How to set a location to create a file from one module to another module

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module project in which my first module is executing the code and generating some data that I am writing into a file and this file should be created in Module2 under src/test/java location.

```
**Module 1:**
@Mojo(name = "dependency-counter", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class DependencyCounterMojo extends AbstractMojo{

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        
        System.out.println("....Mojo execution beginsssssss...."); 
        GenerateData ob=new GenerateData();
        ob.getData();
        
        String fileLoc="./src/test/java/feature";
        File file=new File(fileLoc + ".feature");
        file.createNewFile();
    }

**Module 2:**

src/test/java
 -feature
```

Is there a way by which I will be able to create my file into module2 from module1. How can i set the location that will tell my code in module1 to create new file under src/test/java/feature folder.

Comment: In Maven, you should not write to other modules` directories and especially, you should never write to a directory below `src`. What problem do you want to solve by this?

Comment: I have a framework which have a couple of classes and tests ... I have moved my classes in module1 and executing them from mojo class and then once they get executed then my tests are run using the data passed from module1 to module2. So my tests are created in a file in module1 which I would then run in module2. But this file need to go inside module2 (src/test/java) folder.

Comment: You could deploy the results of the mojo as side artifact (with some classifier) along with module1. Then module2 can download the file, unpack it and use it.

Comment: actually I would want to run the entire flow form getting the data > use data to create tests> run the tests in one go so better if I can get a way to create file under module 2 location

Comment: At least don't create any files under `src`, only in `target`. Creating files under `src` is a cause for deep trouble...

Comment: ok but is there a way I can tell my module1 to create file in Module2